# array.push is not a function - when working with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

Can someone please help me understand whats going on here?

```
let firstArray = [];
firstArray.push(1);
firstArray.push(1);
firstArray.push(1);
console.log("firstArray", firstArray); // result [ 1, 1, 1 ] - as expected.



let secondArray = [1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, item) => {

    console.log("acc", acc);
    console.log("typeof acc", typeof acc);

    // on first passing, the accumulator (acc) is Array[] == object.
    // on the second passing the acc == number.

    // but why?
    /// i expect to get [1,1,1] as my secondArray.
    return acc.push(1);

}, []);

console.log("secondArray", secondArray);
```

**the program crashes with "acc.push is not a function"**

[image: accumulator.push is not a function in reduce]

And inspecting the first logged `accumulator` shows that we have the push method - it's a real function:

[image: array.push not working with reduce]

Comment: `return acc.concat(item);`

Comment: Does `push` return the pushed element? Try pushing on a separate line, then return acc.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The return value of [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is the new length of the array after the push. This means that in the second iteration `acc` is a number, which doesn't have the push method.

The fix is simple - separate the push and return statements:

```js
const secondArray = [1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc.push(1);

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(secondArray);
```

Comment: Why does the second iteration of acc become a number?

Comment: @Ori Drori - just seen your comment - to not confuse beginners: there is no `according.push() ` - in the question code above `acc` is a shortcut for `accumulator` - this comes form functional languages where `folding / reducing` is one of the fundamental operations one performs on a daily basis, and `acc` is a generic name for anything which is `summed up / accumulated`. Is used for trees, dictionaries, state machines, arrays, lists, tasks, anything rely. Pretty wide spread pattern. Given this is about reducing an array, understanding what acc rely stands for is pretty important. That's all :)

Comment: const secondArray = [1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, item) => (acc.push(1), acc), []);

console.log(secondArray);